# Unable to install CiviCRM 5.0.1 as Drupal site admin

Tags: drupal, installation

Just been trying to install CiviCRM 5.0.1 in Drupal 7.58, and when I try to run the install script, I get a message saying I don't have permission to do so:

"You don't have permission to access this page
The installer can only be run by a user with the permission to administer site configuration.

Refer to the online documentation for more information: Installation Guide"

It's a fresh installation of Drupal, and only has the initial admin user - there's nothing unchecked in the Drupal permissions for administrators (but obviously it doesn't have anything related to CiviCRM as the module isn't enabled).

Comment: Was drupal installed as "minimal" or "standard"? I've had problems with various things civi and non-civi when using minimal.

Comment: It was a standard installation (done v. quickly without checking every step in the manual, but didn't hit any errors with installing Drupal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below link might be useful for work around

[Getting permission error when installing CiviCRM under Drupal](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21742/getting-permission-error-when-installing-civicrm-under-drupal)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Went for giving anon users permission to administer site configuration as it's just a test site on a local server - that got me to the install page. Thanks!