# white screen when trying to install civicrm on drupal, which is installed on a subdirectory

Tags: installation

I have a Drupal site installed in a subdirectory, and would like to install the Civi module in it. I have uploaded all the civi files, alas, when I try to install
Civi here:  www.mysite/drupal/civi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php I get a white screen. No error. Have done a lot of search on it to no avail. Thank you!

Comment: Did you look in the webserver log files? Probably the log files gives you a direction of what goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I have checked the error log file. Nothing is captured there. :-(

Comment: That is really strange. This sounds that error reporting is completly turned off at your system.

Comment: And maybe it is related to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21742/getting-permission-error-when-installing-civicrm-under-drupal/21938

Comment: Yeah, I had read this thread. Thank you! the issue in my case is that I get a blank screen when I launch the Civi installer script. No on-screen errors. Aye...  And I also had read in another forum that it's impossible to do. I wonder if adding something in the .htaccess would resolve the issue, unfortunately I have minimal knowledge of this language.

Comment: It might be a .htaccess solution but a white screen could be anything and are the worse errors to resolve and even worse when log files doesn't give any indication.

Comment: I am having this issue also. Nothing in the error logs. The regular log lists that GET accessed the page. PHP7.1 Drupal 7.59, CiviCRM 5.4.0 from a git repository clone of an existing site.

Comment: The only way I've gotten around this issue is by copying the civicrm.settings.php file into `sites/default` and editing the database and user information.

Comment: And then running `drush --include=sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/drupal/drush civicrm-install --dbname=CIVICRMDATABASE --dbpass='PASSWORD' --dbuser=DB_USER --destination=sites/all/modules/contrib --site_url=com.example.devv`