# Drupal Installation Error on Centos

Tags: drupal, installation

I am getting this error during installation.  Has anyone else seen this?

You don't have permission to access this page
The installer can only be run by a user with the permission to administer site configuration.
Refer to the online documentation for more information: Installation Guide

Comment: There is an open [issue on Gitlab](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/18) for this problem (I think). It might be worth adding specifics of your problem to it to help get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes even i face similar problem when i try to install CiviCRM. But i make it work by commenting the line that throws this error.

You can find quick solution [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21909/155).