# CiviCRM 5.4.0 Install "You do not have permission to access this page"

Tags: installation, 5.0

I am stuck on this step:

> Then go to Settings > CiviCRM Installer:
>   http://example.org/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install
>
> ```
> In version 4.7 and above you will see a link on the wp-admin page to the Installer screen
> ```

There is not link on the wp-admin page like it says and if I manually use http://example.org/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install with my domain it gives me a "You do not have permission to access this page" error.

I basically cannot access the installer at all.

Comment: Can you confirm the plugin is active?   Can you give us some details on the hosting environment and the user role/capabilities that you ran the install for?
I just did a clean install from the installation zip of 5.4.0 on WP 4.9.8 on an Ubuntu 16.04 Server with php 7.0 and Apache 2.4 with no issues.   User is an administrator on a single site with capability to edit_users and manage_options.

Comment: Plugin is active. Environment is Shared Hosting with Dreamhost I believe they run Ubuntu LTS and Apache. Pretty typical and meets requirements I have CiviCRM running fine on same server different account.

User is an admin yep with appropriate credentials.

Comment: Could you check the civicrm and webserver logs?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes even i face similar problem when i try to install CiviCRM. But i make it work by commenting the line that throws this error.

You can find quick solution [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21909/155).

Comment: Does not work for me :(

Comment: That is right because the proposed solution is  only for Drupal and you are on Wordpress. I dont have a solution to your problem.

Comment: Any reason for down voting my answer? Does it provide any negative impact?

Comment: because your link goes to a fix for a drupal installation and the question is about wordpress. So your link to the answer does not apply to this question. The answer in the link is really specific to drupal. So it sounds for me as a useless answer.